# Install scikit-learn 1.3.2 on MacOs through conda or pip

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cmake, pip

I am trying to install version 1.3.2 of scikit-learn in MacOs. When I am trying to do this with pip I will get the following:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn==1.3.2

WARNING: Cmake Toolchain failed to determine Cmake-Compilers state
Run-time dependency xsimd found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)
Run-time dependency openblas found: NO (tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake)

../scipy/meson.build:159:9: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have already installed openblas with

```
brew install openblas
```

but it still can't find it for some reason?

I can install scikit-learn with

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

but that downloads 1.3.0 and I can't get it to download 1.3.2, something with package not found.

How can I install scikit-learn 1.3.2 in either conda or via pip?

Comment: is `conda-forge` in your list of channels? The default channels only have scikit learn up to 1.3.0, you will find 1.3.2 on conda-forge though. If you are in a fresh env, try `conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn==1.3.2`